# Correct class for fs.hdfs.impl in hadoop-hdfs 3.0

Tags: java, hdfs

DistributedFileSystem class was removed in hadoop-hdfs 3.0. Can someone suggest the correct class to replace for config set?

With the following line that worked prior to 3.0:
conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());

As per eclipse, we are now being told:
"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem cannot be resolved to a type"

I am able to verify that DistributedFileSystem is present on the jar's leading up to 3.0 and then removed as per jars retrieved from Maven repository.

Answer (score 5):

Now, the class `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem` can be found in hadoop-hdfs-client jar. Sample maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```